# Change ActionBar's title using PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented a custom Actionbar in my project in which I use Tabs navigation. This custom Actionbar shows the product's logo at the right side, and the fragment-tab title dinamically at the left side. So, every time I select a tab to change to another fragment, the title of the Actionbar changes too.

This approach works fine, but now I have modified this to implement PagerTabStrip. To get this I have included relevant code for PagerTabStrip, and quit using Tabs navigation on ActionBar.

The thing is that I don't get to change dinamically now Actionbar's title.

This is the way I have now implemented Actionbar with PagerTabStrip in main Activity:

MainActivity.java

```
/*Inflate your custom actionBar layout*/
final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);

abTitle = (TextView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.abtitle);

actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
/*Hide default icon*/
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
/*Hide default title*/
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
/*Enable custom view*/
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 2;
    /*Tab Titles*/
    private final String tabtitles[] = new String[] { "TEST", "SETTINGS"};
    Context context;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment1 fragmenttab1 = new Fragment1();
                return fragmenttab1;
            case 1:
                Fragment2 fragmenttab2 = new Fragment2();
                return fragmenttab2;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabtitles[position];
    }
}
```

And this is how I changed the Actionbar's title when I used tabs and that seems that isn't working with PagerTabStrip.

In fragments:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.test_title));
```

In MainActivity:

```
public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
    abTitle.setText(title);
}
```

So the thing is, how do I get to change Actionbar's title dinamically using PagerTabStrip? Why this method isn't working with it? Does PagerTabStrip manage fragment's in a diferent way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference on the adapter so that you can get each fragments needed title

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager())
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Also, you'll have to set the title of the actionbar, each time a new page is selected. Add a listener on your `ViewPager` like this:

```
 viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int position,
                            float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    //A new page has been selected. Change the title here
                    String title = adapter.getPageTitle(position);
                    (MainActivity)getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(title);

                    }

      }
```

Have a look on the `onPageSelected` method. This is the callback you need to override and place your setTitle call there.

EDIT: In order to ensure that the correct title is set when the activity is created/recreated/or resumed from the background, do something like this:

```
@Override
void onResume(){
    int pos = viewPager.getCurrentPosition();
    String title = adapter.getPageTitle(position);
    setActionBarTitle(title);
}
```

You'll have to set the reference of your ViewPager outside the onCreate() call though, but I'm sure you'll figure it out ;)

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the new suggested method? I'm facing some throubles when implementing the current suggested method

Comment: Done. Looks like you didn't really need the mViewPager.getCurrentItem() method after all. Check it out

Comment: Ok Alex, just one thing, I think that I'm having throubles with this approach because I'm setting it on ViewPagerAdapter class but, do I have to put it in MainActivity?

Comment: Yup, activity or fragment, depending on where the ViewPager is being initialised. I wrote the above snippet, following your own piece of code, actually :P. The above snippet needs to be called at the same point you are initialising your ViewPager (just after your ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager) call)

Comment: Ok, is working. Just one last thing, This method allows to change the title when a page is changed, but at starting the app, when still no page is changed but the default fragment is being showed, there is no title in the Actionbar. How could I solve this?

Comment: Glad it worked. I've updated the answer with what you asked :)

Comment: Changed getCurrentPosition() for getCurrentItem() and working! Thanks!